# A _standard_ way to use matlab2tikz output from a subfolder

Tags: matlab2tikz

In my tex project I use an ./images/xxx/ directory to save stuff generated by matlab2tikz. Sometimes matlab2tikz generates png's. When I try to "\include" the tikz file it fails to import those for an obvious reason - the tikz file contains the paths to png's relative to itself, not to the main tex file.

Is there a **standard** way to handle such situation (e.g. supply a path prefix to matlab2tikz as an option). Please do not advice postprocessing the tikz file, I'm looking either for built in functionality, or a tex idiom to handle this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few options:

- You can use the option `relativeDataPath` for `matlab2tikz` to set the prefix that is put in the files. This is documented both on the [Wiki](https://github.com/matlab2tikz/matlab2tikz/wiki/The-directory-structure-of-matlab2tikz-output-in-one-picture) and in the help of `matlab2tikz`.
- You can set the `\graphicspath` in your LaTeX file to include all folders where the PNG files may reside. More info in the [graphics](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/graphics) package.

Comment: @HennadiiMadan Don't worry. It has given me the incentive to write a bit better documentation for those parameters.